# Find most recent update in WMS or WFS

Tags: wms, wfs, update, change-detection

We want to periodically poll various WMS or WFS services and do something if the source data has changed. Is there any way to do any of the following:

- find the date of the most recent update to a data layer
- find whether data has changed since a previous request
- get some kind of hash indicating a summary of the data at present

I don't see anything in the specs, but perhaps there is some other mechanism I'm not aware of?

Comment: I'm not sure this type of http request exists within WMS/WFS.  You could store those delta changes though in a database that gets triggered by a certain user editing event.

Comment: These are remote servers that we have no control of, and limited knowledge of.

Comment: I am pretty sure that WMS and WFS do not have such hidden feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few approaches which may help:

### Service level

- `updateSequence` attribute: OGC Web Service (OWS) Specifications provide an `updateSequence` attribute as part of `GetCapabilities` responses which articulate a value a client can use to detect changes. Keep in mind this is for the entire service (not layer/featuretype specific).
- HTTP response headers: some implementations may or may not support the `ETag` or `Last-Modified` (HTTP header Response fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Response_fields)

### Layer/FeatureType level

- WMS time dimension: for WMS layers which provide temporal query, one can inspect a Layer's `Dimension name="time" ...` construct (if supported) to detect changes in the temporal aspect(s).  Note this is for WMS only
- WMS `MetadataURL`: from a WMS/WFS's Layer/FeatureType, one can fetch the given metadata (XML) from the `MetadataURL` element and inspect/detect for changes (depending on the metadata format)

Note that these are optional features that the standards provide, so your mileage may vary across implementations.